# BackboneJS test with jasmine if parameters are passed to fetch

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I have a Backbone Collection and I need to pass some parameters to the .fetch({data : {gender : 'male'}}). Is there a way to test with jasmine that the parameters are passed?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably achieve that by using the method in the example below.
**Please note that**, the below code will intercept the fetch-call and return, the call will not reach the server. If you would like to have the server-side emulation, then you would need to use Sinon or some other such similar methods.

```
    describe("People collection" function() {
        var people = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            // ...
        });

        function searchPeople(people, data ) {
            people.fetch(data);
        }

        it("must verify the fetch parameters!", function(){
            var param = {data : {gender : 'male'}};
            // Set up the spy.
            spyOn(people, 'fetch').andReturn(); // Warning: this makes the call synchronous, Fetch actually won't go through!

            // Now perform the operation that would invoke Collection.fetch.
            searchPeople(people, param);

            expect(people.fetch).toHaveBeenCalled();            // Verifies the fetch was actually called.
            expect(people.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(param);   // Verifies that the fetch was called with specified param.

        });
    });
```